# Printで出した結果をデスクトップに保存したい

Tags: python, excel

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("PSD online data1.csv", thousands=',')
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
df.corr()
import pandas as pd
from scipy  import stats
stats.pearsonr(x, y)
p_value = df.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x,y)[0])

print(p_value)
**ここでPrintした結果をパソコンのファイルに保存したいです**
```

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるでしょう。[\[python\] print()でデータをファイルに書き込む](https://qiita.com/pytry3g/items/aa38d8c2acf59b90aaac), [pythonのprint関数の使い方をまとめてみる。](https://www.pytry3g.com/entry/python-print), [print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, flush=False)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p_value.to_csv('ret.csv')`にてCSVファイルとして保存できます。